# Exceptions connecting to the webservice from Android app using ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, exception, ksoap2

I have an Android app where I use ksoap2 to connect to web service, but sometimes I get errors from the clients. When I am testing myself on my device, everything is ok, so I am not sure where could be a problem.

I get these exceptions:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to example.com/91.10.10.10 (port 443) after 1800000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to example.com/91.10.10.10 (port 443) after 1800000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
java.net.SocketException: failed to connect to example.com/91.10.10.10 (port 443) after 1800000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

or

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

or

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5cb6d638: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
```

I use this function to call webservice funcions:

```
private SoapObject makeCallToWebService(String soapAction, String method, PropertyInfo[] properties, boolean runInBackground) {
    int retry = RETRY_COUNT;
    int count = 0;

    if (mShouldRetryWhenError == false) {
        retry = 1;
    }

    while (count < retry) {
        count++;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, method);

        if (properties != null) {
            for (PropertyInfo property : properties) {
                request.addProperty(property);
            }
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);;

        HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(HOST, PORT, FILE, TIMEOUT);

        transport.debug = true;
        transport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");

        try {
            transport.call(NAMESPACE + "#" +  soapAction, envelope);

            SoapObject res = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

            return res;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            if (count == retry) {
                if (!runInBackground) {
                    handleError(method);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());

            if (!runInBackground) {
                handleError(null);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing using wifi? Maybe your problem comes just using 3G. If so, you should check this out:

[Android application working on WIFI and 3G(Without proxy), but not working on 3G(If proxy and port are assigned)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617451/android-application-working-on-wifi-and-3gwithout-proxy-but-not-working-on-3g/18759907#18759907)

Comment: I use wifi for connection.

Comment: I mean: when you test, everything is ok, and you're testing using wifi. Also you said users sometimes connect right and sometimes wrong. So I suggest to check if problems come only using 3G, because there is a bug in Android 4.1 as is detailed in the given link.

Comment: I got this error not only in Android 4.1 but also 2.3.6 and 4.2 but I will test it. Thanks.